# Expression Engine Categories - Only super admin can change category on edit entry screen

Tags: categories, permissions, administration

I want to be able to give content members on my site the ability to choose which category an article should be listed within but at the minute only the super admin has this ability.

I've looked through the member group permissions and tried various options but nothing is working.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find an answer to this James? I've got a site on 2.7.3 and having the same problem.

Comment: Hi Elliot, the issue for me was related to Publish Page Layouts. For more info please see https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/245999/ and https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/publish_page_layouts.html

Comment: Thanks James. Looks like it's something weird with Publish Layouts. They've never really worked well, I hope EE3 completely rethinks these.

Answer (score 2):

Did you also check CP Home > Administration > Categories > Specific Category Group > Edit Category Group?

There are additional permissions settings there:

Can Edit Categories

Can Delete Categories

Also - are you sure you have assigned the category group to the channel, and also make sure you don't have a Publish Page Layout that is hiding the category options from non-superadmin users.

Comment: Thanks Micheal I have tried both of these are these is no restriction on the these options that would affect the admin / content members. None that I can see anyway :(

Comment: If you have allowed access overall to categories via Justins answer, and have set per-category-level permissions per my answer, and are not hiding the controls, then all I can think is that somehow you have a bug and should work with EE tech support on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Members > Member Group > Group in Question > scroll down to Channel Posting Privileges > Can Edit / Add New Categories and select yes for that member group as seen in the picture below:

[image: Allow categories editing.]

Comment: Hi Justin, I have set this to Yes and it still isn't working unfortunately.